# How to run hooks with LetsEncrypt certbot after auto renewal?

Tags: server, 20.04, letsencrypt

When installing certbot on Ubuntu (20.04) it will automatically run `certbot renew` via cron or systemd.

If I place hook scripts in `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/(deploy|post|pre)` will certbot also run these, or do I need to add '--deploy-hook' to the certbot command in cron|systemd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cerbot will run scripts from `renewal-hooks`. `--deploy-hook` is not required.

Don't forget to set `chmod +x` for scripts.

If you run

```
sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

certbot executes the hooks too.

Comment: Just want to chime in --dry-run DOES NOT run deploy hooks. As per manual for --dry-run: "...deploy-hook commands do not run, unless enabled by --run-deploy-hooks"

Answer (score 2):

The answer to OP's question is yes. Any scripts in the `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/{deploy,post,pre}` will automatically be run.

However, I don't know if the behaviour of certbot has changed since the original answer but `--dry-run` will not run hooks.

If you check the logs of a dry-run though it will let you know which scripts would have been executed.

```
2023-05-20 19:27:23,171:DEBUG:certbot._internal.renewal:Dry run: skipping updating lineage at /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.co.uk
2023-05-20 19:27:23,171:INFO:certbot._internal.hooks:Dry run: skipping deploy hook command: /etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/deploy/generate-pkcs12.sh
```